# Code coverage reports for unit tests and integration test using jacoco

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I am using jacoco maven plugin to generate a code coverage reports. I am looking for a solution, in most of the blogs both unit and integration testcases are located in same application. I would like to have my unit testcases in one application and QE test scripts in different application and finally I have to merge my code coverage reports from unit testing and integration testing reports

Example:

- Project A --> Contains application source code and unit tescases.
- Project B --> Contains only integration testscripts.

Comment: What exactly is your question and your problem ? merging reports ? getting them to work in sonarqube ? please make a precise question.

Comment: A hosted solution like Codecov may accomplish you needs. I'm happy to elaborate once you answer @benzonico comment above

Comment: Hi benzonico, i want my both integration and unit testcases results in my sonarqube dashboard. My unit testcases are there in one project and integration testcases are in another project.